# OpenEHR ADLParser error using se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser and org.openehr.adl.parser.AdlDeserializer

Tags: argument-dependent-lookup, openehr

We are trying to deserialize an ADL file (ADMIN-ENTRY), but an error occurs when using both ADLParser and ADLDeserializer.

Using se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser return this error message:

```
se.acode.openehr.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <V_LOCAL_CODE> "\"at0108\" "" at line 109, column 112.
Was expecting:
    "}" ...
    
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.generateParseException(ADLParser.java:7327)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.jj_consume_token(ADLParser.java:7191)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2832)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_object(ADLParser.java:2632)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attr_values(ADLParser.java:2868)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2831)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_object(ADLParser.java:2632)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attr_values(ADLParser.java:2868)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2831)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_object(ADLParser.java:2632)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attr_values(ADLParser.java:2868)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2831)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_object(ADLParser.java:2632)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attr_values(ADLParser.java:2868)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2831)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_object(ADLParser.java:2632)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attr_values(ADLParser.java:2868)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_attribute(ADLParser.java:2831)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object_body(ADLParser.java:2604)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.c_complex_object(ADLParser.java:2587)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.cadl_text(ADLParser.java:2553)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.arch_definition(ADLParser.java:738)
    at se.acode.openehr.parser.ADLParser.archetype(ADLParser.java:295)
```

Using org.openehr.adl.parser.AdlDeserializer return this error message:

```
org.openehr.adl.parser.AdlParserException: 1:0 extraneous input '﻿' expecting {ARCHETYPE, TEMPLATE, TEMPLATE_OVERLAY}
335:0 mismatched input 'ontology' expecting <EOF>
    at org.openehr.adl.parser.AdlDeserializer.parse(AdlDeserializer.java:68)
    at org.openehr.adl.parser.AdlDeserializer.parse(AdlDeserializer.java:51)
```

This is the ADL file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m7vQ7fw7EvQI58t3kbL73Py713DYV-Q9/view?usp=sharing

Does anyone know how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the construct with DV_TEXT is illegal on line 109.
The same construct is used  a few line below this one, try removing this one and see if you get the error on that location.

What are you trying to achieve? Is it meant to be a regular expression?